# create a txt file in PowerShell list of all running services

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a txt file in PowerShell that provides a list of services that are running.  This what I came up with but it keeps on giving me an error message that says its not valid.

```
Get-Service | Export-txt -path "C:\Windows\Temp\services.txt"

Get-Service | where {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Export-txt -path "C:\Windows\Temp\services.txt"
```

Comment: The error message says the term Export-txt is not recognized as the name of cmdlet

Comment: What commandlet were you trying to use? `Export-txt` doesn't exist.

Comment: Where would I need to make the changes to the two Scripts

Comment: Theres not cmdlet names `Export-txt`, what you want is `Out-File`.

Comment: What I am trying to do is create a txt file which lists all of the running services in that file

Comment: I tried this Get-Service | Out-File -path "C:\Windows\Temp\services.txt" but i recieved an error message that says a permater cannot be found that matches parameter name 'path'

Comment: Out-File doesn't take a parameter called "Path". See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: I will give that a try and I will reply back thanks

Comment: It worked Thank you

Comment: Awesome! Recommend you brush up on whats available to you using `Get-Command` and using the built-in Help system, `Get-Help Cmdlet-Name`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no commandlet called `Export-txt`.

One option is to use [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.1#examples). It uses `-FilePath` as a parameter (or no named flag).

```
Get-Service | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Windows\Temp\services.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no cmdlet by the name of `Export-txt`. To get a list of cmdlets you can use, you can think logically and apply that to `Get-Command`. Running `Get-Command` will get you a list of all available cmdlets you may use in accordance with your Posh version.

`Get-Command *out*` returns a list of cmdlets you can send *out* to something. Same logic applies to `Get-Command "Export*"`.

```
#This gets you all services
Get-Service | Out-File "C:\Windows\Temp\services.txt"

#This gets you only running services
Get-Service | where {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Out-File "C:\Tmp.txt"
```

Use `Get-Help Out-File` to see how the cmdlet is used and what parameters it accepts. It also lists examples you can use.

Comment: added an extra asterisk in out, sorry!